# Custom Share URL Google+ with multi parameters

Tags: javascript

i trying to create button ShareURL Google+ with URL Arguments similar Facebook and Twitter URL below but it not working, it just only pass with the url.

```
https://plus.google.com/share?url={url}&title={title}&description={content}
```

```js
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id={app_id}&display=page&href={url}&title={title}&description={content}
```

```js
https://twitter.com/share?url={url}&text={title}&via={via}&hashtags={hashtags}
```

I'm looking for some answers or suggestions or any solution similar FB.ui?

Comment: What makes you think that you can use `&title={title}&description={content}` ? According to the docs you cannot. https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/

Comment: thanks @PedroLobito , this my mistake because i read this post https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls so i thought that Google+ can use title and desc like facebook and twitter. so do you have any solution for custom share similar FB.ui ?

Answer (score 1):

did you read the docs to see if other fields were allowed?

https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/#share-link

According to the docs, it only accepts URL & and hl (for language).

Comment: omg , thanks @imvain2. i got a mistake. so do you have any idea to custom share Google+ similar FB.ui ?